# repeat the elements in a list

Tags: python, list, for-loop

so this is my list:

```
my_list = [['a','b','c'],['d','e','f']]
```

I want to have the output that times 2 times each:

```
final_list = [['a','a','b','b','c','c'],['d','d','e','e','f','f']]
```

And this is what I am doing:

```
final_list = []
for new_list in my_list:
    for my_new_list in new_list:
        for i in range(2):
             final_list.append(my_new_list)
```

but it shows:

```
final_list = ['a','a','b','b','c','c','d','d','e','e','f','f']
```

how do I fix it? and by the way I wish to do it with for loop. Thank you

Comment: Would `final_list.append([my_new_list])` do the trick?

Comment: What are the full requirements here? Can the arrays be nested arbitrarily deep, or is it limited to what you've posted here?

Comment: no it doesn't. it will be like [['a'],['a'],....]

Comment: @RedAlert it is what it is, cannot be nested :(

Comment: That's not what I asked. Just look at my answer, if that covers it then you've answered my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will only work for parsing an array of arrays, which I assume should be enough:

```
final_list = []
for sublist in my_list:
    temp_list = []
    for item in sublist:
        temp_list += [item] * 2
    final_list.append(temp_list)
```

Comment: if I want to triple the element, do I need three lines of temp_list.append(item)?

Comment: Yes. You can even do something like `temp_list += [item] * n`, where `n` is the amount of times you want an item to repeat.

Comment: do you mean temp_list.append[item]*n ? I thought list does not work with +=

Comment: Are we talking about python here? You can use the + operator to add items to a list. edit: you can't use .append() to get this functionality, actually

Comment: oh ok never mind, thank you, it does work! but instead of using * something, does 'for i in range(2)' also work?

Comment: Yes you can use that, though I tend to stay away from looping over the range() function in python when it can be avoided.

Comment: +1 for clean approach. @user3025931: Using `range(n)` in Python generates a list. Looping over a range while looping over a list is kind of redundant and can be of some magnitudes slower (someone please correct me here in any case) than the method Red Alert showed above. :)

Answer (score 1):

```
def change(L):
    res = []
    for i in L:
        temp = []
        for j in i:
            temp.append(j)
            temp.append(j)
        res.append(list)
    return res
```